# Which statistical test is most suitable for comparing temporal abundance data?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, ecology

I am looking to compare differences in density of individuals of a species of zooplankton. I have calculated density for every meter from 0-100m, for four different time periods. As such, I have an integer value (depth), a factor (four levels, one for each season), and a numerical value (density).

Can anyone suggest a suitable method of analysis to determine whether the distribution of this zooplankton species differs significantly from one season to another? I'm not interested in comparing means, as this would disregard the spatial significance of my data.

I intend to investigate the relationship between these density results and environmental parameters using canonical correspondence analysis.

Below are 4 plots, one for each time period, comparing the density of individuals at each (binned) depth.

[image]

Comment: As a start, plot the four profiles (against depth) and show us! And tell us a little more about how you want to use this ...

Comment: Why would a mean disregard the spatial significance?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I've edited the post and included the plots. I am investigating depth distribution of a species of plankton from the same site, in four different time periods. I have further data with physical parameters, but before I try to explain the differences in distribution, I want to demonstrate a statistical significance.

Comment: @rw2 Because while there might not be a difference in number of individuals between time periods, there certainly is a difference in where individuals are located in the water column. Comparing means might tell me there is, or is no significant difference between each time period, but it would only be refering to the abundance.

Comment: So could you not just test if there's a difference in the mean depth that plankton were found in each time period? If there's no difference in abundance you might want to demonstrate that with another test, as maybe that is of interest.

Comment: @rw2 Do you have any suggested methods to do that? I've read a lot about compairing weighted mean depths, but because the data I have optained has exact depths (it was collected using a video plankton recorder) this method doesn't seem valid

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding how the data was collected. Does each plankton (or count of them) not have an associated depth? If it does, then just compile the data into separate lists of depths for each season, and test whether there is a difference in the mean depth between seasons. i.e. with an anova.